# Get previous href after match using grep, sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a not formmated html file where I need to get the href link that's just before a match... My html file looks like:

```
<a href="url1.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test1]</a><a href="url2.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test2]</a><a href="url3.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test3]</a>
```

So now I need to get the href content before [Test2] pattern and the expected return is url2.com.

I'm not a sed or awk expert and I don't think it's possible with a pure grep command.

I can know if my partern exists inside file using the command below, but I don't know how to get the previous href.

```
grep -o '\[S06E04\]' file.html
```

I really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to process data that is not line-delimited, such as XML, with tools that expect line-delimited data. Use something like `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs : The html seems like minified...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\)">.*\[Test2\].*/\1/p' file
url2.com
```

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=href=")[^"]*(?=">[^<>]*\[Test2\])' file
url2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[[\\]"]' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i == "Test2") print $(i-2)}}' w.txt

url2.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po 'href="\K[^"]+(?="[^[]+\[Test2\])' file.html
```

- `href="` matches literally before the desired URI, `\K` discards the match
- `[^"]+` gets the desired portion
- The zero width positive lookahead pattern, `(?="[^[]+\[Test2\])`, ensures that the match is followed by anything in square brackets but `[Test2]`

---

Similar logic using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]]href="([^"]+)"[^[]+\[Test2\].*/\1/' file.html
```

---

**Example:**

```
$ grep -Po 'href="\K[^"]+(?="[^[]+\[Test2\])' <<<'<a href="url1.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test1]</a><a href="url2.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test2]</a><a href="url3.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test3]</a>' 
url2.com

$ sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]]href="([^"]+)"[^[]+\[Test2\].*/\1/' <<<'<a href="url1.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test1]</a><a href="url2.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test2]</a><a href="url3.com">Bla Bla Bla [Test3]</a>'
url2.com
```